# customize android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked

Tags: android, listview

I want to change `drawable` of predefined checked in

`android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked` it is possible?

**From** Checked [image]

and Unchecked [image]

**To** Checked [image]

and Unchecked [image]

And I don't want to create custom list item.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible but only by using a custom layout with a standard adapter, you can do this by defining the same ids as the predefined layout with your custom layout but only changing the ones you want. Unfortunately in this case, the source code for android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked doesn't have a drawable by default. (https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/layout/simple_list_item_checked.xml) it uses the `checkmark` attribute

```
android:checkMark="?android:attr/textCheckMark"
```

I'm unsure whether you can change this, but i still reccomend using a custom layout with a standard adapter, just compare the original with your current layout and define all the same attributes with a drawable instead of a checkmark, like in the example below: It's up to you though.

```
<CheckBox android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
 android:text="new checkbox"
 android:background="@drawable/checkbox_background" 
 android:button="@drawable/checkbox" />
```

This is how you assign custom images saved in the @drawable directly depending on the state of the checkbox.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item android:state_checked="true" android:state_focused="true"
  android:drawable="@drawable/first" />
 <item android:state_checked="false" android:state_focused="true"
  android:drawable="@drawable/second" />
 <item android:state_checked="false"
  android:drawable="@drawable/third" />
 <item android:state_checked="true"
  android:drawable="@drawable/fourth" />
</selector>
```

further reading: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton.html#setChecked%28boolean%29

more here: http://www.android-ios-tutorials.com/android/custom-android-checkbox-radiobutton/

Comment: Actually i'm using setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked,mAssetListName)); and this give me From drawable as i given in question. But i want To drawable.

Comment: ah i see, i'll change the answer.

Comment: if this didn't help, let me know how.